# Quick way to search strings in a dataframe in r

Tags: r, algorithm, subset

I have a vector contains some strings like this

```
f <- c("a","b","c")
```

And I have a data frame (df) that contains some columns:

```
    h1  h2  ...
1   a   20  ...
2   a   50  ...
3   a   60  ...
4   e   70  ...
5   e   80  ...
  ...
```

Now I am trying to write code to find out the rows that contains same string as I have in the vector.

i.e: sample output

```
    h1  h2  ...
1   a   20  ...
2   a   50  ...
3   a   60  ...
  ...
```

My solution is to use a for loop to go through every item in f then use grep to find the rows I want. And use rbind() to put the rows together.

```
for(item in f){
    newdf <- rbind(newdf, df[grep(item, df$h1),])
}
```

However my dataset is really big and this takes forever to find all the rows I want.

I am wondering if anyone has a better solution.

Comment: You want `match` or `h1 %in% f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be much faster than a for loop:

```
df[df$h1 %in% f,]
#  h1 h2
#1  a 20
#2  a 50
#3  a 60
```